# JQuery custom validation get error messages from Rails ( need for i18n )

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, validation, internationalization

I'm using Rails with the JQuery plugin, and have some really complicated validations for one of my forms that I decided to use JQuery for.  For very simplified example, the fields A1, A2, ... A4, B1 - B4, and C1 - C4.  Just a few of the rules are:

- if a user inputs any data into A,B, or C, then they MUST input into all four fields.
- if a user inputs any data into A or B, they must also complete the other (B or A).
- no fields's value may differ from it's neighbor by more than 10%

Actually only the average of A, average of B, and average of C are stored in the database / model, so I'm relying totally on client-side JQuery that I wrote to validate (all in application.js).  I finally got this working quite smoothly.  My rails model is not bothering itself with any of these validations.

The problem is, I need to be able to grab the error messages from Rails, because of i18n ( I need English and Chinese).  For example "Field is required" or "Must be a number".  I am using i18n successfully with the rest of my app... I just don't know how to use it with JQuery.

Any ideas how to do this, or points in the right direction?

(I should note that I never used JQuery or Javascript before 3 days ago, so I'm a pretty big newb in this area)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For i18N you can use jQuery.i18n.properties plugin. I am using it in my app, its easy to integrate.

http://keith-wood.name/localisation.html